# Use lang-lisp highlighting for Stack Overflow answers tagged Emacs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

It's pretty common for Emacs related questions to only be tagged 'Emacs'. For example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4924389/509706). This question includes Emacs lisp code, but it's not highlighted. This is a pretty common occurrence for Emacs questions.

Could we add Emacs lisp highlighting to Emacs questions?

Comment: I must admit I've not used it but isn't emacs more general purpose than that?

Comment: @RichardTingle Regardless of how general it is, it is based on LISP and all plugins and user functions are written in LISP (ELISP to be precise - Emacs's version of LISP).

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't mean it's just used for Lisp programs, does it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey true, but the large majority of code snippets in Emacs questions are written in elisp.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think he means that most (or, virtually all) [emacs] posts using code tags are asking about or answering with emacs configurations and plugins, which are written in (E)LISP.

Comment: Seems to me like a better solution would be to add the Lisp tag to the question (which already works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've turned on LISP formatting rules for [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs). This may require overriding the defaults in a few cases, but it appears that *most* of the code present in Emacs questions is Emacs Lisp, even when the question itself isn't *about* Emacs Lisp, so forcing both tags to be present just makes [elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elisp) redundant.